# Multiple Queries to Fill One DataTable

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, datatable

I currently have 12 fairly simple SQL queries which are used to pull data meeting different criteria to create a status page for displaying the priority order of received support emails.

However, what I need to do is have a single DataTable that displays the following:

```
Col1  |  Col2  |  Col3  |  Col4
     Data from SQL Query 1
....  |  ....  |  ....  |  ....
....  |  ....  |  ....  |  ....
     Data from SQL Query 2
....  |  ....  |  ....  |  ....
....  |  ....  |  ....  |  ....
     Data from SQL Query 3
....  |  ....  |  ....  |  ....
....  |  ....  |  ....  |  ....
              etc
```

So each query is run, then its data added to the datatable after the previous query (no sorting takes place, and all rows are added in the order each SQL query returns them).

I have tried using an SQL `UNION` statement to combine all SQL queries together, however the results returned become ordered by ID across  all rows which isn't what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data doesn't have any ORDER other than that which you specifically specify. If you want to order the data in a specific manner, add it to your query.

If you want the rows from query 1 first, then add an extra column indicating that to your query

```
 select 1 as priority, field1, field2 from ...
 union
 select 2 as priority, field1, field2 from ...
 order by priority
```

Comment: He may want to use `UNION ALL`, since the queries are independent to begin with.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson A valid consideration, but the priority column would make all the subqueries return different results

Comment: Yep, the result will be correct, but UNION (unless the optimiser is smart) does extra work to keep things distinct when they already are.